# Ontology based research

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege4

I am doing my masters and my professor wants me to create an ontology for a whole IOT based indoor Sensor Web system. There are many things I am not sure about like how can i make instances for sensor driver and middle ware class. i am using Protege.
I want to ask if its possible that i feed new temp light or humidity values to my ontology on a daily basis through some web service to be able to reason over it. I am really confused by this idea. give me some suggestions 
And please do not ask me to go Google it myself of course i am doing it but i want some suggestions from people who have worked in this area.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My own [home automation system](http://blog.abodit.com) is based on a semantic-web-like description of rooms, floors, sensors, light switches, ... with relationships between them such as 'contains', 'controlled by', 'adjacent', ... Reasoning over this ontology allows commands like "play pop in first floor" to find all the media zones in that area and start playing music on them. Currently simple entailment is all it does (and all that's needed) to deduce such facts, although I can see a few cases where it would be nice to have a more powerful reasoner.

It would be unusual to attempt to store all the time-based sensor data in RDF (it's a huge dataset even in its simplest form). More likely you would reason over the static description of the system and then use your reasoned facts to process the data, e.g. to find t*he average temperature yesterday in rooms connected to the kitchen* you would use the reasoner to find the temperature sensors that apply and then process the temporal data filtering it by the temporal query.